# SQL Query that compares two set of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like the following one

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [MyTableID]    [int]           IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ContainerID]  [int]           NOT NULL,
    [FIELD_A]      [nvarchar](15)  NOT NULL,
    [FIELD_B]      [nvarchar](15)  NOT NULL,
    [FIELD_C]      [nvarchar](15)  NOT NULL,
    [FIELD_D]      [nvarchar](50)  NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [MyTableID] ASC )
    WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In simple terms `FIELD_A`, `FIELD_B`, `FIELD_C` and `FIELD_D` are grouped by `ContainerID`.

Considering that each container contains about 2k records, I would like to execute a query that returns the differences between two `ContainerID`. For example, while comparing container 1 and container 2, I need to know:

- How many records are present in 1 and not in 2 and vice versa
- How many records are present in both containers

Which is the simplest way to get those results?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at [EXCEPT / INTERSECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)?

Comment: Actually I did not tried anything in SQL. I am not so skilled with that. I have everything working with a C# algorithm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start:

```
-- rows for 1 but not in 2:

SELECT FIELD_A, FIELD_B, FIELD_C, FIELD_D FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE ContainerID = 1
EXCEPT
SELECT FIELD_A, FIELD_B, FIELD_C, FIELD_D FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE ContainerID = 2;

-- rows for 2 but not in 1:

SELECT FIELD_A, FIELD_B, FIELD_C, FIELD_D FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE ContainerID = 2
EXCEPT
SELECT FIELD_A, FIELD_B, FIELD_C, FIELD_D FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE ContainerID = 1;

-- rows in both:

SELECT FIELD_A, FIELD_B, FIELD_C, FIELD_D FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE ContainerID = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT FIELD_A, FIELD_B, FIELD_C, FIELD_D FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE ContainerID = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks! I did never thought it was so simple :(

Answer (score 1):

This ought to work, you'll have to index all four of the "field_x" fields and it still wont be quick

```
SELECT isnull(t1.Field_A,t2.Field_A) Field_A, isnull(t1.Field_B,t2.Field_B) Field_B
, isnull(t1.Field_C,t2.Field_C) Field_C, isnull(t1.Field_D,t2.Field_D) Field_D
,CASE WHEN t1.MyTableId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
,CASE WHEN t2.MyTableId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM
(SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ContainerId=@ContainerId1) t1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ContainerId=@ContainerId2) t2
ON t1.Field_A=t2.Field_A AND t1.Field_B=t2.Field_B 
AND t1.Field_C=t2.Field_C AND t1.Field_D=t2.Field_D
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. THis query is a bit more difficult to understand for a newbie but it works as well :)